# Thunderbird Chat - Additional Chat Protocols

Tags: skype, thunderbird

In Windows I have the chat client Trillian, that supports multiple chat protocols (Facebook, Google+, Skype, AOL, ICQ, MSN, Yahoo and many others).
Skype does not need to be installed, just Trillian.

I plan to switch to Ubuntu, where Thunderbird is installed.
Thunderbird has its own chat client that supports for example Facebook and Google+.
The other chat protocols are not supported in Thunderbird.

Is there a way to add support for Skype, AOL, ICQ, and Yahoo?
Skype and ICQ would be most important.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Trillian with Ubuntu 20.04, and it is working very well for me. Download the deb or rpm from https://www.trillian.im/get/linux/6.1/linux.html

Answer (score 0):

The ["Additional Chat Protocols for Thunderbird" addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/additional-chat-protocols/) is not supported in Thunderbird 24.0, the default version in Ubuntu. You can either [downgrade](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/) your Thunderbird version, or use another IM client such as [Pidgin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pidgin/). Pidgin supports many protocols and integrates very well with the Ubuntu UI.

Thunderbird chat supports the XMPP protocol. See whether the service you want to use supports XMPP.

Comment: My intention is to have everything (emails, contacts, chats) in Thunderbird. One client for all...

Answer (score 0):

Empathy and Pidgin are popular choices for multi-protocol instant messaging clients in Ubuntu Linux. They're both based on the same library libpurple and therefore roughly the same features.

Unfortunately there is no FOSS solution for Skype without the proprietary client, because Skype doesn't allow that.

Comment: But why can Trillian in Windows use Skype (Skype does no even have to be installed in Windows)?

Comment: Probably because Cerulean Studios has an agreement with Skype/Microsoft that a FOSS project can't make. Since Tuesday there's a [beta for Trillian Pro](http://blog.trillian.im/?p=2835) on (Ubuntu) Linux though.

Comment: I tested the beta of Trillian Pro in Ubuntu and this is very "beta". Skype is not yet implemented.